# Is this just a wordpress plug-in? We'd like to try to do this for a LGBT audience.

Tags: discussion

Wondering how wordpress Answers works? I like it!

Comment: No. [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This site is part of StackExchange family of sites (http://stackexchange.com/). Definitely not running on WordPress :). And your question probably belongs on meta - after a little rephrasing.

Comment: Why o why has this jumped up the queue?

Answer (score 6):

This site is part of the [Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites](http://stackexchange.com/). New sites can be proposed via [the Area51 site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/). There is already [a LGBT proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13507/lgbt), but it needs more work to define the scope. A (maybe) related proposal, [Everything You Always Wanted to Know about Sex but were Afraid to Ask](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3303/everything-you-always-wanted-to-know-about-sex-but-were-afraid-to-ask), is already in the next stage.

The network runs on software and servers from stack overflow internet services inc., but there are [open source alternatives](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267) that you can run yourself.